# Know if a model exists in my Gazebo Simulation

Tags: ros, gazebo, roscpp, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I would like to know how to check if a model exists in my simulation. I wrote a C++ node who change position of a model (with set_model_state) but I would like to verify in this node if the model really exists. Does someone have an idea ? Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266043/know-if-a-model-exists-in-my-gazebo-simulation/) by [blevesque](https://answers.ros.org/users/29495/blevesque/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Answered](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16706/know-if-a-model-exists-in-my-gazebo-simulation/) at http://answers.gazebosim.org

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.ros.org/users/4654/chapulina/) with karma: 366 on 2017-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0